Checking Ampleness by Faithfully Flat Descent on the Base
Let $f:X \to S$ be a morphism of schemes and $\mathcal{L}$ an invertible sheaf on $X$.
Question: Can  relative $f$-ampleness be checked by faithfully flat descent on the base? Namely, if $h: S' \to S$ is faithfully flat and $f': X \times_S S' \to S'$ base change of $f$ along $h$, then, if we can show that $(h')^*\mathcal{L}$ is $f'$-ample, then this would imply that $\mathcal{L}$ is already $f$-ample.
What about very ampleness?
Motivation: This question is "on base" version of this one. There, as Will Sawin's example show we cannot expect that to check ampleness of $\mathcal{L}$ we can pass to arbitrary faithfully flat cover  $g:X' \to X$ on level of $X$ as "total space"/ domain side and check ampleness there.
One sufficient additional assumption is to require for $g$ to be additionally finite.
Here, I would like to discuss the other special case where we assume that $g$ (in notion above $=h'$) comes as pullback from faithfully flat map $S' \to S$ on the base.

https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0D2P

I'd like to comment that I have no idea why this question was closed. It's true that there is just a reference for this in the stacks project (which is not too hard to find), but it seems like a legitimate question to me. Similarly, I am not sure what the downvotes are for. I wonder if my glib response contributed to people thinking the question is low quality. The question is fine.

Let me add that in Goertz&Wedhorn's book it is also proved in Prop 14.56 with slightly differerent methods
